# Cassandra on Amazon EC2 with Elastic IP addresses

Tags: cassandra

Can I used cassandra on EC2 instances without Elastic IP addresses? I believe in that case any instance that goes down, would create an issue.

If I use Elastic IP addresses for the cassandra nodes, I have to configure them such that they use the Public IP address for internal communication (gossip etc.). But that will increase the network latency.

Please suggest how should I configure my nodes such that the problems can be minimized.

Answer (score 2):

My answer would be, use Rackspace Cloud Servers instead because you get better i/o performance as well as both public and internal IPs.

But there are several people in the community using EC2; I'd ask on the cassandra-user list if you insist on that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Many people (me included) use cassandra on Amazon's EC2 without issue. As the internal IP addresses are prone to change at will you'll just need to use your internal EC2 DNS names (not your public IP address or public DNS name as that would both be a security hole and also Amazon would charge you for all your Cassandra traffic).

It does mean that if your Cassandra node goes down for any reason then you'll lose the data on that node (unless you're using persistent storage which is slower) but this can easily be fixed by increasing your replication factor (we use RF=3)

Answer (score 1):

We use a VPN solution that has worked exceptionally well with EC2 & Cassandra which allows us to **not** use Elastic IP's.  Some information about it can be found here.

- [Spreading MongoDB across EC2 regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962974/spreading-mongodb-across-ec2-regions)
- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201105.mbox/%3CBANLkTi=mB5joMKZHasodJcPUJOQ7+V7O-Q@mail.gmail.com%3E

Now, this option isn't for everyone, but allows us to mitigate the issues with EC2 nodes changing IP addresses and not having to use Elastic IP.  We also find that we receive performance increases by *NOT* using the Amazon interfaces (internal/external).  Don't ask me why .. I don't know enough about their architecture to be able to explain it -- expcet that it just does!

Further, it allows us to leverage nicely the suggestions @jbellis proposes, to use RackSpace.  We have a mixed provider setup .. so that we can leverage EC2, RackSpace and our own internal hosted nodes.  Being vendor / service provider agnostic is quite important to me...